# MySQL SUM up until a specific date for each year

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `customer_invoices` table containing a fields `invoiced_at` as date & `total_price`, I need the SUM of the `total_price` of the invoices from the start of each year till the same day as today, grouped by year, and starting from a specific year that I provide.

What I did so far :

```
public function totalIncomeToCurrentDayByYear($startingAt)
{
    return CustomerInvoice::selectRaw('sum(total_price) as total')
        ->where('customer_invoices.status', Status::VALIDATED)
        ->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(invoiced_at,'%Y') as year")
        ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(invoiced_at,'%Y') >= $startingAt")
        ->groupBy('year')
        ->get()
        ->pluck('total', 'year');
}
```

I need to have a result similar to this : (in this case I get the SUM of the whole year which is Not what I want):

```
totalIncomeToCurrentDayByYear(2003); // ==> 

  #items: array:14 [▼
    2003 => "144.52"
    2006 => "11455.00"
    2007 => "27485.40"
    2008 => "39268.08"
    2009 => "37434.19"
    2010 => "443631.75"
    2011 => "2275159.26"
    2012 => "3874576.94"
    2013 => "4994901.19"
    2014 => "5968874.72"
    2015 => "7250182.95"
    2016 => "9017509.81"
    2017 => "10704557.00"
    2018 => "12637778.13"
  ]
```

For example, today is `January 23rd`, for each line in the array should represent the SUM of `total_price` during that year up until `January 23rd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below query

```
CustomerInvoice::whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(invoiced_at,'%Y') >= $startingAt")
   ->where('customer_invoices.status', Status::VALIDATED)
   ->whereRaw('MONTH(invoiced_at) < MONTH(NOW()) or 
    (MONTH(invoiced_at) = MONTH(NOW()) and DAY(invoiced_at) <= 
    DAT(NOW()))')
   ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(invoiced_at) invoiced_year' ),
    DB::raw('SUM(total_price) total_price'))-
    >groupBY(DB::raw('YEAR(invoiced_at)')
   ->orderBy(DB::raw('YEAR(invoiced_at)')->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't get me the total for every year `up until the same day as today` as I mentionned.

Comment: @dwix i added another where that thinks to s solve your problem, please check that

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's working. Can you take sometime and explain to me what the`where` you added actually does ?

Comment: your welcome, if that help please select my answer as the solution."
->whereRaw('MONTH(invoiced_at) < MONTH(NOW()) or 
    (MONTH(invoiced_at) = MONTH(NOW()) and DAY(invoiced_at) <= 
    DAT(NOW()))')" was the where that added and filtered the result based on month and day of date. for more information about month and day function see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Answer (score 0):

Put another where filter such that invoice date is less than current date.

```
public function totalIncomeToCurrentDayByYear($startingAt,$currentDate) { return CustomerInvoice::selectRaw('sum(total_price) as total') ->where('customer_invoices.status', Status::VALIDATED) ->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(invoiced_at,'%Y') as year") ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(invoiced_at,'%Y') >= $startingAt")->whereRaw("invoiced_at <= $currentDate") ->groupBy('year') ->get() ->pluck('total', 'year'); }
```

Comment: I get the same result (which is the total for the whole year) with or without that filter.